# Can't make onclick work on an injected button through content script in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-injection

I'm developing a chrome extension that injects a button on web page. I'm able to inject the button successfully however i cannot apply a `onclick` function on it. I wrote button injection code in `content.js` which is as follows

```
jQuery('body').append('<button onclick="myFxn();" class="vwsItBtn" style="height: 25px; width: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 1; font-size: 12px; z-index: 867530999; display: block; padding-right: 4px !important; margin: 0px; border: 2px solid rgb(254, 208, 70); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 4px; font-weight: bolder; text-shadow: #FED046 0px 0px 1px; color: #36373B; text-align-last: end;"><img id="myImgVw" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block; padding: 0px; left: 2px; position: absolute; vertical-align: middle !important; top: 3px;" src="'+chrome.extension.getURL("imgvwextsitbtn.png")+'"/> Schedule</button>');

jQuery(function(){
    function myFxn(){
        alert('This is working!');
    }
})
```

Now i get an error that myFxn is not defined. Now this function is quite simple but how do i make it work?
This is the first time i'm developing a chrome extension and i'm pretty sure there is some other way of doing it. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the `myFxn()` function is declared within the scope of the jQuery document.ready handler, whereas it needs to be global for the `on*` attribute to be able to access it. Try this:

```
jQuery('body').append('<button onclick="myFxn();" class="vwsItBtn" style="height: 25px; width: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 1; font-size: 12px; z-index: 867530999; display: block; padding-right: 4px !important; margin: 0px; border: 2px solid rgb(254, 208, 70); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 4px; font-weight: bolder; text-shadow: #FED046 0px 0px 1px; color: #36373B; text-align-last: end;"><img id="myImgVw" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block; padding: 0px; left: 2px; position: absolute; vertical-align: middle !important; top: 3px;" src="'+chrome.extension.getURL("imgvwextsitbtn.png")+'"/> Schedule</button>');

function myFxn(){
    alert('This is working!');
}
```

Better yet, put your styling in to separate stylesheets to make your HTML simpler and better separated from the styling and also don't use the outdated `on*` event attributes and use unobtrusive Javascript to attach your event handlers instead. As you're using jQuery already, here's an example of how to do that:

```
.vwsItBtn {
    height: 25px; 
    width: 80px; 
    position: absolute; 
    opacity: 1; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    z-index: 867530999; 
    display: block; 
    padding-right: 4px !important; 
    margin: 0px; 
    border: 2px solid rgb(254, 208, 70); 
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    font-weight: bolder; 
    text-shadow: #FED046 0px 0px 1px; 
    color: #36373B; 
    text-align-last: end;
}
#myImgVw {
    width: 15px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 0px; left: 2px; 
    position: absolute; 
    vertical-align: middle !important; 
    top: 3px;
}
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').append('<button class="vwsItBtn"><img id="myImgVw" src="' + chrome.extension.getURL("imgvwextsitbtn.png") + '"/>Schedule</button>');

    $('.vwsItBtn').click(function() {
        alert('This is working!');
    });
});
```

Comment: I already tried this before but this is the error: (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFxn is not defined

Comment: Added to this, what i just noticed that console is showing that this error is in index file however there is no such page in my extension. This 'index' page is of the website in which i'm injecting my script. But why is it looking for myFxn in index?

Comment: This worked, had done a silly error. Thanks a lot. Your answer showed me the correct way!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: It's important to understand **why the first solution still doesn't work**. Content scripts [live in an isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment); creating the element with an onclick attribute will create a handler in the page's context, while the handler is created in the content script context. The second solution avoids this problem by keeping everything to the content script context.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for the info. If you check my 2nd comment on this answer, i was thinking about something similar and later realized what you mentioned after understanding this answer

Comment: Was wondering if you can help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930597/how-pinterest-extension-store-temporarily-images-from-a-web-page-and-then-acce) as well?